# Do I need to use "of"

Tags: prepositions, transitivity

> My mother finally approved **of** our plan.
>   My mother finally approved our plan.
>
> My parents approved **of** my marrying girl.
>   My parents approved my marrying girl.

Do I need to use "of" or can be discarded ?

Comment: Did you look in the dictionary first? [Here you go](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/approve)

Comment: @No More Secrets, don't give me silly comments, First read the question properly, Question is about "of" not for "approve".

Comment: @JNRaju Agree, the question revolves around the use of **of**, but As Secret rightly said, you have to look for the verb. Because different verbs licenses different prepositions. Such use of preposition is called *grammatised use of preposition*. Try some good learner's dictionary, for example Oxford Advanced Learners' Dictionary or whatever suits you. And look for the verb, here *approve*.

Comment: Well beyond the issue being asked about, by far the largest problem in these sentences is "my marrying girl," which is just wrong. You *could* say "my marrying [a|the|this|that] girl" and it wouldn't be wrong, though it would sound weird. Most English speakers would go with *marriage* though, for something like "My parents approved my marriage *to* the girl," or something like that.\

Comment: @JNRaju Sorry, I was under the impression that people with questions here are expected to do a minimum of research first, and share that in the question. If you wonder why I think that, you might look here: [How to Ask](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @NoMoreSecrets They are, but that wasn't a particularly helpful link. I don't see any usage notes on 'of' there, although the examples don't include the word.

Comment: @DCShannon > a :  to accept as satisfactory <hopes she will approve the date of the meeting> b :  to give formal or official sanction to :  ratify <Congress approved the proposed budget> intransitive verb

:  to take a favorable view <doesn't approve of fighting>

Comment: @NoMoreSecrets That makes sense after reading Stoney's answer, but I certainly didn't notice the slight difference there when I first scanned it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Transitive *approve X* and intransitive *approve **of** X* actually have two different meanings.

- *Approve X* means to give X a formal 'approval' which is required to go forward. For instance, a bank approves a loan, meaning that it consents to lend the money, or a government office approves a building proposal, meaning that it allows the construction to take place.
- *Approve **of** X* means to "regard X favourably" or "express a favourable opinion of X", and that good opinion isn't ordinarily a requirement for an action to be carried forward.

So which you use depends on what sort of power your mother or your parents exercise over the proposed action. If you can't execute the plan or marry the girl without their approval, then you should use transitive *approve*; if you're free to execute the plan or marry the girl even if they don't regard those actions favourably, you should use intransitive *approve of*.

Comment: I am wondering how "approve of" can be used as an intransitive verb. For example, "Do you approve of my idea" strikes me as a transitive verb- the object is "my idea". I am struggling.

Comment: The verb is not *approve of*, but *approve*; *of* is a preposition which heads the preposition phrase which is the verb's complement. This is obscured by loose talk about "phrasal verbs" which fails to distinguish "particle verbs" from idioms involving specific verb+PP combinations where the sense of the combination cannot be 'derived' from the separate meanings of the verb and the preposition.

Comment: Thank you, Could you provide me with a sentence with the intransitive one. I only can think to "He asked me, I approved of"

Comment: @Cardinal No: the point is that *of* is not a piece of the verb; it introduces the entity who receives the subject's favour. "I introduced Lydia to my parents and Mom approved." That's an alternative to "...and Mom approved **of her**."

Comment: @StoneyB Constructions such as "approve of" superficially appear to be verb+preposition but sometimes are deemed "phrasal verbs" (http://grammar.about.com/od/pq/g/phrasalverbterm.htm) when there's a clear distinction in meaning between the phrasal verb and the unadorned root verb.  Take, for example "shut down" (see http://notaverb.com/shutdown if you think the space should be omitted). It conveys a completely different meaning from "shut" and "shut up".

Comment: @MontyHarder Indeed; but linguists object to the term because it confuses at least three distinct sorts of construction with different syntactic behaviors, because it misrepresents the verb+preposition collocation as a 'phrase' or constituent, and because it promotes the syntactic absurdity of treating the object of the preposition as the Direct Object of the verb--as Cardinal does in these comments.

Comment: @StoneyB There's nothing absurd about two-word verbs, just as there's nothing absurd about two-word nouns.  To me, Cardinal is right:  What's absurd is the notion that "approve" could be an intransitive verb. If someone approves, they're approving _something_.  In the rare case the (direct) object is omitted ("My mother didn't approve.") it's clear that the object is implied by the preceding context.

Comment: @MontyHarder *Approve of* is not a constituent: *My mother approves of my girlfriend, and I approve, too*, but not **She approves of my girlfriend and I approve of, too*. *Girlfriend* here is object of the preposition, not the verb. And the preposition may pied-pipe: *The girl of whom my mother approves*.

Comment: I'd add that in most conversation, neither party will understand this difference, nor think anything of the use of either (until they start asking questions: "I approve", "Of Whom?"). This is (clearly) a potentially confusing matter, which StoneyB has done a good job of explaining. @MontyHarder it's intransitive because there _is no direct object_, that's what intransitive means. I would have been just as confused as you had I not learned German grammar (I'm English native, no formal education in linguistics).